# Perspective projection alternate matrix (SOLVED)

Tags: matrices, geometry, image-processing

A lot of perspective projection matrices I've seen look something like this:
$$\left [\matrix {1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&z&0}\right]$$
where $z$ is the z-coordinate of the point.

What I wonder is will this matrix work also?
$$\left [\matrix {1&0&0&0\\0& 1&0& 0\\0&0& 1&0\\0&0&{\left(\frac{20}{17}\right)^z}&0}\right]$$

The reason why I think so is because I think foreshortening is exponential in relation to distance. When I implemented this into a custom program, it worked without looking weird.

Edit: Apparently, the second projection will not have a singularity of projection and the first matches the definition better.

I didn't test the second for enough points. For example, the ray from $\left [\matrix {0\\0\\0}\right]$ past $\left [\matrix {1\\1\\1}\right]$ will look weird as it goes to a point then comes back down like it's being sucked into a black hole.

In short, $f(x)=x0.85^z$ (where z is a constant or a function of y or x or both) sometimes has a maximum.

Comment: I've put alignment tabs in your first matrix.  If you do the same with your second matrix, then the columns will be correctly aligned.